# F - set of the subsets of set {1,...,n}. Prove |F| <= n if...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathbb{K}_n = \{1,...,n\}$ and $\mathbb{F} \subset 2^{\mathbb{K}_n}$

1) $ \forall{A} \in \mathbb{F_n}: |A| = 1 \mod 2 $

2) $ \forall{A,B} \in \mathbb{F_n}: A \neq B \to |A \cap B| = 0 \mod 2 $

Prove that $|\mathbb{F_n}| \leq n$

Proof:
I use mathematical induction to prove the statement

Base: $n = 1$, $\mathbb{F_1} = \{ \{1\} \} $ It is not contrary to both conditions. And $|\mathbb{F_1}| \leq 1$

Let $n = 2$.Now $\mathbb{F_2}$ one of following: $\{\{1\}\}, \{\{2\}\} or \{\{1\},\{2\}\} $ They are not contrary to the conditions. Hence, $|\mathbb{F_2}| \leq 2$.

Inductive step from $n-1$ to $n$:

$\mathbb{F}_{n-1} \leq n - 1$.
Let $ \mathbb{F}_{n-1} = \{A_1, A_2,...,A_k \}$

Add the element $\{n\}$. $\mathbb{K}_n = \mathbb{K}_{n-1} \cup \{n\}$

We can choose $\mathbb{F}_n = \mathbb{F}_{n-1} \leq n-1 < n$.

But what if $ \exists B: B \in \mathbb{F}_n$ and $n \in B$

Consider following case:

1) $\mathbb{F}_n = \mathbb{F}_{n-1} \cup \{n\}$ It is not contrary to the conditions and $|\mathbb{F}_n| \leq n$

2) Add $\{n\}$ to $A_i \in \mathbb{F}_{n-1},1 \leq i \leq k$. It will be contrary to the conditions.

3)Let $K = A_{i_1} \cup A_{i_2} \cup ... \cup \{n\} $ Hence, $ |K \cap A_{i_1}| = |A_{i_1}| = 1  \mod 2 $ .It is contraty to the first condition

That's all. But I think my proof is not quite right. What is your opinion of it?

Comment: The base is already weird. You need to show that *any* family $\mathbb{F}$ satisfying the requirements has at most $n$ elements, not to give an example of a family satisfying it. The induction step is also meaningless.

Comment: @zhoraster Why is base wrong? I considered the situation when $n = 1$ and get that $K_n = {1}$. And so on.

Comment: I wrote why it is wrong. What is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $k$ sets, i.e. $|\mathbb{F}|=k$. Let $M$ be the $k\times n$ "incidence matrix" for the sets.  That is, $M$ has a row for each set $A_i$, a column for each element of $\mathbb{K}_n$, and $M_{ij}=1$ if $j\in A_i$, else $M_{ij}=0$. We'll be doing arithmetic mod $2$, so you should think of $M$ as a matrix over the $2$-element field.

Now look at $G=M M^T$; this is a $k\times k$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $|A_i\cap A_j|$ mod $2$. By condition 1, $G_{ii}=1$, and by condition 2, $G_{ij}=0$ if $i\ne j$. So $G$ is the identity matrix, so it has rank $k$. But now we're done since
$$k=\mathrm{rank} \,G \le \mathrm{rank} \, M\le n.$$